# Can octal number be represented in exponential form in java?

Tags: java

Can octal number be represented in exponential form in java?
when i try using 
'int x=00.76e4;'
Java compiler takes it as normal integer and does not recognize it as octal number.

Comment: There is not a floating point octal literal format. I don't think anyone really wants one.

Comment: I think you mean scientific notation which uses the base 10, i.e  10^2, that is often written like e2 for 10^2 so its not usable for base 8. Exponential form is for any base, x^y, e.g 4^2 or 7^6